# Query not returning results(report) but displaying message instead

Tags: jquery, linq, report

when I run my code and there are no errors, but it doesn't display the report, instead returns the following statement. "An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code".
This in my controller with the query:

```
public ActionResult Report_3()
        {            
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetChart3()
        {
            var query = db.Researcher
              .Where(r => r.Submission.Count > 0)
              .Select(r => new
              {
                  Name = r.FirstName + ' ' + r.Surname,
                  NumberOfSubmissions = r.Submission.Count
              }
                     );


            return Json(query.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Report_3 View:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

                    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        google.load("visualization", "1.1", { packages: ["table"] });
                        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

                        function drawTable() {
                            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                            data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
                            data.addColumn('string', 'NumberOfSubmissions');

                            $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetChart3")", null, function (chartData) {
                                $.each(chartData, function (i, item) {
                                    data.addRow([item.Name, item.NumberOfSubmissions]);
                                });

                                var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

                                table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: false, width: '35%', height: '200px' });
                            });
                        }
                    </script>



                    <th scope="col">
                        Filter by Name
                        <input id="txtPrjName" onkeyup="searchColumn('Name')" type="text" />
                    </th>

                    <div>
                        <div id="table_div"></div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Try to convert `.ToList` at the end of `db.Researcher` query and just return `query` in `Json`

Comment: do you mind elaborating, do you mean like this?                                  return Json(query db.Researcher(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: sorry I am very new to LINQ

Comment: No no.. I said `db.Researcher
              .Where(r => r.Submission.Count > 0)
              .Select(r => new
              {
                  Name = r.FirstName + ' ' + r.Surname,
                  NumberOfSubmissions = r.Submission.Count
              }
                     ).ToList();` and then `return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: i see. thank you for the help

Comment: unfortunately it still returns the same message: https://www.dropbox.com/s/erre8u4bsdvhf6i/message.PNG?dl=0                   this is what I put in the controller:                                                                        var query = db.Researcher.Where(r => r.Submission.Count > 0) 
            .Select(r => new { Name = r.FirstName + ' ' + r.Surname, NumberOfSubmissions = r.Submission.Count } ).ToList();
            return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89781/discussion-between-kivan-ilangakoon-and-guruprasad-rao).